# three.js canvas, sphere turn or float right

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, three.js

i try out to get the sphere to turn right in a very slow tempo. here is my source code : i have created a new contaier with canvas inside, you can see the code. what i have to include that the sphere turn in a slow tempo? here I'm also i have my git repository on github: see the image inside https://github.com/SpaceG/SpaceSphere. here i have also, found another example, with a sphere: this roundball truns a float very slow in the same point, this is excat waht i need: http://rectangleworld.com/demos/DustySphere/DustySphere.html This turn left i need in my code below]. You can also download my repo or fork it and get fixxed my issue here.

Here is the Html Doc :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<style>

        body {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        a {
            color:#0078ff;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

The Javascript Code to make the Sphere possible:

```
        <script>

        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,

        mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0,

        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 4,
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 4,

        SEPARATION = 600,
        AMOUNTX = 10,
        AMOUNTY = 10,

        camera, scene, renderer;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            var container, turnAngle, separation = 100, amountX = 50, amountY = 50,
            particles, particle;

            container = document.createElement('div');
            container.setAttribute('class', 'space-id');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 275, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 5, 10000000 );
            camera.position.z = 100;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();



            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            // particles

            var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
            var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

                color: 0xffffff,
                program: function ( context ) {

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
                    context.fill();

                }

            } );

            for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {

                particle = new THREE.Sprite( material );
                particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                particle.position.normalize();
                particle.position.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 10 + 450 );
                particle.scale.multiplyScalar( 2 );
                scene.add( particle );

            }

            // lines

            for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3( Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1 );
                vertex.normalize();
                vertex.multiplyScalar( 450 );

                geometry.vertices.push( vertex );

                var vertex2 = vertex.clone();
                vertex2.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 0.3 + 1 );

                geometry.vertices.push( vertex2 );

                var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: Math.random() } ) );
                scene.add( line );
            }

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 4;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 4;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        //

        function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length > 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

            }

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY + 200 - camera.position.y ) * .05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an Image about the Goal of the Project, that the round ball turn to left in slow tempo, are some one here give me tips? lets up the Good Work. Thanks lot.

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle ?

Comment: I'm also have created my jsFiddle here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceG/0w149z6o/)

Comment: but, would be good, that the zoom in would be stay, only the animation turn right... in a slow tempo. thats all. but i didn't get it here. peace. ps. just like a disco ball...

Comment: @Nimish here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceG/0w149z6o/ maybe you can help'

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the ball to spin like it does in the example, you can do the following:

```
// Declare these before the call to init();
var group = new THREE.Group();
var rotationSpeed = 0.001; // Increase/decrease to control speed of rotation.
```

And, instead of `scene.add(particle);`

you do `group.add(particle);`

then `scene.add(group);`

The same goes for the lines:

instead of `scene.add(line);`

do `group.add(line);` (here you don't need to add to the scene since you're adding to the group that is already in the scene.)

Then the key line that was missing in the render loop:

```
group.rotateY(rotationSpeed); // Rotates the ball with speed 'rotationSpeed'
```

Here is a fiddle of what it looks like with these changes:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w149z6o/3/)

Comment: thanks a lot, but the zoom does not now... need it with the zoom ine when mouseover... ?! any idea. best and thanks alot.

Comment: You can just reenable the zoom, put `camera.position.z = 100;` first then uncomment lines 164 and 165;

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0w149z6o/3/

Comment: ! yeah, how cool is that !!!!!! <3 you are a genie! This is very first Canvas, need to understand all these points with the (scene, camera, and rotateY(rotationSpeed). I have thought at the point of rotate. but i have found some examples, but these goes upwards rotate. didn't know about Y and X . Thanks a lot for your nice Issue Help, this make me to understand all. peace! :)

Comment: No worries! glad I could help. Accept the answer if it helped you enough that you think it might help others.

Comment: yes, cool, but, now, i try out the script to give in the HTML a ID - like <div id="spacesphere"></div> that the full code give an ID out in the HTML. right now, it give out automaticly a id. but you can't but in a html header or so..